# If v1,v2,...,vp be eigenvectors of a matrix A corresponding to distinct eigenvalues λ1,λ2,...,λp, respectively, then v1,v2,...,vp linearly independent

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here`s a proof that I found for this theorem:
[image: Theorem 1.3. If v1, v2, . . . , vp be eigenvectors of a matrix A corresponding to distinct eigenvalues λ1, λ2, . . . , λp, respectively, then v1, v2, . . . , vp are linearly independent. Proof. Let k be the smallest positive integer such that v1, v2, . . . , vk are linearly independent. If k = p, nothing is to be proved. If k < p, then vk+1 is a linear combination of v1, . . . , vk; that is, there exist constants c1, c2, . . . , ck such that vk+1 = c1v1 + c2v2 + · · · + ckvk. Applying the matrix A to both sides, we have Avk+1 = λk+1vk+1 = λk+1(c1v1 + c2v2 + · · · + ckvk) = c1λk+1v1 + c2λk+1v2 + · · · + ckλk+1vk; Avk+1 = A(c1v1 + c2v2 + · · · + ckvk) = c1Av1 + c2Av2 + · · · + ckAvk = c1λ1v1 + c2λ2v2 + · · · + ckλkvk. Thus c1(λk+1 − λ1)v1 + c2(λk+1 − λ2)v2 + · · · + ck(λk+1 − λk)vk = 0. Since v1, v2, . . . , vk are linearly independent, we have c1(λk+1 − λ1) = c2(λk+1 − λ2) = · · · = ck(λk+1 − λk) = 0. Note that the eigenvalues are distinct. Hence c1 = c2 = · · · = ck = 0, which implies that vk+1 is the zero vector 0. This is contradictory to that vk+1 6= 0.]

**Can someone explain why necessarily Vk+1 != 0?**

Comment: By definition eigenvectors are $\neq 0$ and $v_{k+1}$ is an eigenvector

Comment: If $A$ is any matrix, and $\lambda$ is any real number, then $A\mathbf 0 = \lambda \mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$. If we allowed $\mathbf 0$ to be considered an eigenvector, then every value would be an eigenvalue and concept would be meaningless.